# Prisma error when I want to install my dependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install, prisma

I'm working on project with the ORM Prisma. When I do `npm i` after pushing my project with git on my server (hosted by Plesk), I've got the next error:

[image: NPM ERROR MESSAGE]

When I do `npm i` on my local project, everything is working good.

I tried to install an old version (2.28.0) on the server but the same error message is displayed.

I also did the next steps: deleted `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, `npm cache clean --force` then `npm i`. But it's always the same issue...

The log :

```
16491 verbose npm  v6.14.14
16492 error code ELIFECYCLE
16493 error syscall spawn
16494 error file sh
16495 error errno ENOENT
16496 error prisma@2.28.0 preinstall: `node scripts/preinstall-entry.js`
16496 error spawn ENOENT
16497 error Failed at the prisma@2.28.0 preinstall script.
16497 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
16498 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Did you look at the log file?

Comment: @Anubisoft I edited my post with the log messages

Comment: Maybe you're running out of physical memory. Creating a swap file may help.

Comment: I finally found a solution, I set ```scripts-prepend-node-path``` to ```true``` in my npm config. Thanks @Anubisoft for helping me :)